# jQuery each this

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var slides = $(".promo-slide");
slides.each(function(key, value){
    if (key == 1) {
        this.addClass("first");
    }
});
```

Why do I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'addClass'
```

From the above code?

Comment: Try wrapping `this` in `$()`, like this: `$(this)` to make sure it's treated like a jQuery object.

Comment: Although one can see why you thought it was, this isn't actually related to function scope.

Comment: @T.J. yes, I realize that now... re-tag?

Comment: Probably, and change title. Pretty much just a straight jQuery question. Best,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Inside jQuery callback functions, `this` (and also `value`, in your example) refers to a DOM object, not a jQuery object.

```
var slides = $(".promo-slide");
slides.each(function(key, value){
    if (key == 0) { // NOTE: the key will start to count from 0, not 1!
        $(this).addClass("first"); // Or $(value).addClass("first");
//------^^----^       
    }
});
```

BUT: In your case, this is easier:

```
$(".promo-slide:first").addClass("first");
```

And when all `.promo-slide` elements in the same container, a solution in pure CSS is *even* easier:

```
.promo-slide:first-child {
    /* ... */
}
```

As an aside, I find it a useful convention to prefix variables that contain a jQuery object with a `$`:

```
var $slides = $(".promo-slide");
$slides.each( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: 1 Minute, 5 upvotes === jQuery effect. Also the each loop is 0 based so he's adding the class "first" to the second element.

Comment: @Orolin: ...because `this` within the `each` function is a reference to the raw DOM element, so if you want to use jQuery functions, you have to make a jQuery instance for that element: [Details in the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: @Tomalak, I think `.each` gives indexes starting from 0, so you should do `$('.promo-slide:eq(1)')` instead, in your second code fragment.

Comment: @Raynos, @Shrikant: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Will fix this.

Comment: @Raynos: Regarding the "jQuery effect" - I find that a little embarrassing myself. There are far better and more "costly" answers (in terms of time needed to write) on this site that hardly catch a vote, while the really obvious ones go through the roof in no time.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to do:

```
$(this).addClass
```