# JQuery: usage of "this" in an .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery each this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409039/jquery-each-this)

I have a loop that iterates over every element of a certain class:

```
$(".myclass").each(function(i) {

});
```

I'm trying to get children of that element with `this.find("tag")`, but it gives me an error. Inside that loop, what, does `this` refer to? What about `$(this)`?

Comment: Please read the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery). Its examples shows how to use `this` properly in callbacks. Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1051782/218196.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is the raw DOM node. If you want to use jQuery functions on it, you need to use `$(this)`.