# Dynamically Insert input/data to JQuery Ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to insert input to jQuery ajax call like this

```
function Insert(FormName, DivName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "" + FormName + ".aspx/GetData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var Records = xml.find("Table");
            if (Records.length > 0) {
                var Main = {};
                $.each(Records, function () {
                    var record = $(this);
                    var ColName = record.find("Column_name").text();   //Getting Column names from database
                    var ColValue = GetColumnsValue(ColName, DivName);  // getting columns value in webform.
                    Main.ColName = ColValue; // adding columns value dynamically to Main, this line is not working                     
                });
                //adding columns one by one directly is working fine
                //Main.Id = GetColumnsValue("Id", DivName);
                //Main.StudentName = GetColumnsValue("StudentName", DivName);
                //Main.RegNo = GetColumnsValue("RegNo", DivName);
                //Main.Marks = GetColumnsValue("Marks", DivName);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "" + FormName + ".aspx/Insert",
                    data: "{MainValues: " + JSON.stringify(Main) + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (d) {
            alert(d.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Inserting columns one by one is working fine. But I want to Insert columns and their values dynamically. So I am getting names of columns directly from database and trying to Insert through loop.
But this trick is not working.

Following code is working fine when I am adding all columns and their values one by one.

```
Main.Id = GetColumnsValue("Id", DivName);
Main.StudentName = GetColumnsValue("StudentName", DivName);
Main.RegNo = GetColumnsValue("RegNo", DivName);
Main.Marks = GetColumnsValue("Marks", DivName);
```

But when I am trying to add columns and their values dynamically, it does not work. Considering `ColName` as a column name.

```
$.each(Records, function () {
                    var record = $(this);
                    var ColName = record.find("Column_name").text();   //Getting Column names from database
                    var ColValue = GetColumnsValue(ColName, DivName);  // getting columns value in webform.
                    Main.ColName = ColValue; // adding columns value to Main, this line is not working                     
                });
```

Here is code for GetColumnsValue

```
function GetColumnsValue(ColumnName, DivName) {
    var all = document.getElementById(DivName).getElementsByTagName("*");
    var controlid;
    var Found, ColumnValue;
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        Found = "N";
        controlid = all[i].id;
        if (controlid.length > 0) {
            var CtrlName = $("[id*=" + controlid + "]").attr('id');
            if (CtrlName.substr(CtrlName.length - 3, 3) != "_NI") {
                switch (CtrlName.substr(0, 3)) {
                    case "txt":
                    case "lbl":
                    case "cmb":
                    case "dte":
                        var c = CtrlName.substr(3, CtrlName.length - 6);
                        if (c == ColumnName) {
                            ColumnValue = $("[id*=" + CtrlName + "]").val();
                            Found = "Y";
                        }
                        break;

                    case "chk":
                        var c = CtrlName.substr(3, CtrlName.length - 6);
                        if (c == ColumnName) {
                            if ($("[id*=" + CtrlName + "]").prop('checked') == true)
                                ColumnValue = "Y";
                            else
                                ColumnValue = "N";
                            Found = "Y";
                        }

                        break;
                }
                if (Found == "Y")
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (Found == "N")
        return "N";
    else
        return ColumnValue;
}
```

Comment: I saw your post and you have said that you want to insert columns and names dynamically ? What exactly do you mean by that ? Can you print your `Records` array on a console.log ?

Comment: As it is posted here, inside jQuery callback functions, this (and also value, in your example) refers to a DOM object, not a jQuery object. Check this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409039/jquery-each-this    To my knowledge, I think it would be better to use a `Array.prototype.forEach()` for handling the `Records` object

Comment: @OrisSin Suppose I have 10 columns in my database table. I don't want to Insert inputs one by one like Main.Id, Main.StudentName and so on.  I just want to get all the columns and add them dynamically like code above.

Comment: Can you post your function `GetColumnsValue` ?

Comment: Inside your `GetColumnsValue` function you are re-assigning your variable `ColumnValue` with no value. That doesn't make a lot of sense as you are already passing the variable on top of your function. One other thing that I would like to see is have a bit of an idea of what structure does your xml file has. I would like also to see your HTML DOM so that I am able to reproduce more or less something similar.

Comment: @OrisSin Maybe some loose coding in `GetColumnsValue` function but that's not our topic. The main concern is, how can I Input columns names dynamically, not one by one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256474/discussion-between-oris-sin-and-shaiwal-tripathi).

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to retrieve the information from your ajax call and subsequently get all the fields from your xml file and print them into your `innerHTML`, I had to remove some of the aforementioned code.

As I can't reproduce a snippet for this as there is extra xml code, I will write down every section and what it does specifically on the comments inside the code.

Instead of a HTTP POST request, I have used a GET method so I would be able to retrieve the document from my webroot directory.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="es">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
   <script src="/lib/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <section id="printArea">

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function Insert() {
            $.ajax({
                // Instead of a POST, I have used a GET method so I would be able to retrieve locally the document from my webroot directory.
                type: "GET",
                // get the url or back-end call in this case in which you retrieve the info of your xml tree, be it books, oranges, whatever
                url: "../Content/books.xml",
                //dataType has worked directly for me so far 
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml){
                    var xmlDoc = xml;
                    // get the nodelist of your data
                    let books = xmlDoc.documentElement.children;

                    //convert node list to array so you can print all columns from your xml file
                    let my_arr = Array.from( books );
                    // the area to print all the data 
                    let printArea = document.getElementById("printArea");

                    if( my_arr.length > 0){ 
                        // forEach function to iterate through the converted array of the xml list
                        my_arr.forEach(function(element){
                            var a = 0;
                            // the tags or labels that are inside each item of the xml list
                            var nodes = element.querySelectorAll("*");
                            for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++){
                                printArea.innerHTML += '<div class="row"' + ' id="data"' + a + '"' +">";
                                printArea.innerHTML += '<div> ' + nodes[i].localName +': ' + nodes[i].innerHTML + ' </div>';
                                printArea.innerHTML += '</div>';
                            }
                            printArea.innerHTML += '</br>';
                            a++;
                        });
                    }
                   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }

        Insert();
    });
</script>
```

And last but not least, the xml code which I used is this:

**XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

That is one approach and I deem that is quite neat. Of course there are way many other ways to do this. The same way can be done with a POST request to retrieve the xml list.

I have printed out each book on the innerHTML and have separated each block with a breaking space. For doing it more homogeneous, javascript Datatables would be nice to use so you can group each field and create a table with multiple rows for each entry.